# Why are equivalent categories not the same as isomorphic categories?

Tags: category-theory

In algebra we consider two structures to "equivalent" iff they are isomorphic. But apparently in the category of categories, equivalent categories needn't be isomorphic. This goes against my intuition of isomorphism, which I so far thought to be the category theoretic "definition" of equivalent. Why, and what's the right way to think about isomorphisms/equivalences?

Comment: I don't know if this answer was already given in the other thread, but a very big difference is that an isomorphism of categories induces a bijection between the sets of objects of two small categories; on the other hand, for every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a category ith $\kappa$ objects equivalent to the terminal one.

Comment: Isomorphism of categories is, more often than not, too strict to be useful. Equivalence is a different, bit relaxed, notion of 'sameness'. A good analogy is the difference between homeomorphic topological spaces and homotopy equivalent topological spaces. The former is much stronger, but sometimes we would like to consider homotopy equivalent spaces as 'the same'. You saying 'equivalent categories need not to be isomorphic in the category of categories' is as saying 'homotopy equivalent spaces need not to be isomorphic in the category of topological spaces'.